# how to plot a scatter plot if there are hundreds of rows in a column using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

x axis is cluttered on the chart with 100 rows.How to deal with this kind of columns?

```
  plt.scatter(data=ipl,x='budget',y='player')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try showing every nth tick-label on the x-axis

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(data=ipl,x='budget',y='player')

n = 4

for idx, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if idx % n != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: i tried plotting for nth point as well still the x axis looks messy

Comment: @Kishan : try the new solution

Comment: If i increase n value the x axis look better.But how to sort the currency value in x axis

Comment: @Kishan : If you want more help, then provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)